# How to check if textbox is non-empty and that its value is greater than 0 and not text?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xhtml, input

I want to check if a textbox value is empty and also if the textbox is greater than 0 with IF OR function via Javascript.

My code is below:

```
if(qty != "" && qty <> "0"){

//

}
```

Where qty is the name and id of the HTML input field

THIS IS THE SOME PORTION FROM THE FULL UPDATED CODE.

```
    if(qty != "")
    {
if(/^\d+$/.test(qty.value)){
var value = parseint(qty.value, 10);
sizeID = document.getElementById("size" + colID + prodID).value;window.location = "/_nCartAddToBasket.asp?ProductID=" + prodID + "&ProductColourID=" + colID + "&ProductSizeID=" + sizeID + "&Qty=" + qty + "&fgID=" + fgID;
}else{
alert("You must enter a numeric value in the quantity field.");}
}else{
alert("You must enter a quantity before adding to your basket.");}
}
```

Comment: do u mean a textfield or a textarea?

Comment: Textfield

`code`<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" /> Enter Quantity:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I edited your question a little in order to have it make some sense.  Your text element cannot be both empty and greater than zero at the same time.

```
var qty = document.getElementById('qty');

if (/^\d+$/.test(qty.value)) {
  var value = parseint(qty.value, 10);
  // whatever ...
}
```

That makes sure that the value of the text element is a string of one or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tbVal = parseInt(document.textbox.value,10) // or jQuery: parseInt($('#textbox').val(),10);
if (!isNaN(tbVal) && tbVal > 0){
  document.textarea.value = tbVal // $('#textarea').val(tbVal);
  // code here
}
```

Comment: This is correct *except* that `parseInt()` does not care if there's garbage after some digits - in other words, `parseInt("12hello")` returns the numeric value 12 and doesn't complain about the "hello".

Comment: @Pointy: true, I should probably revise it to re-assign the parsed value. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

```
var textbox = $get(id);
if(textbox && typeof(textbox.value) == 'number' && textbox.value > 0)
{
//do something here
}
```

Comment: $get() is the shorthand for document.getElementById()  but thinking about it, it might only work for .NET instances.  Sorry should have mentioned that, been working with .NET for too long, it's becoming second nature.

Answer (score 0):

according to what you wrote, you may like a check like this one

```
<script>
function check(value){
if(value=="" || (typeof(value==='number') && value > 0))
alert("The textfield is empty OR its content (value) is a number greater than 0 (> 0)");

}
</script>

<input type="text" onBlur="check(this.value)"/>
```

Comment: The value property of a text element will always be a string after user interaction.